# How to obtain debug/release conditional compiling in C++ program

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator, conditional-compilation

In a large C++/Qt/QMake/qtcreator project I would like to perform some tests, but only when I am compiling with the debug flag.

Is there a way to tell g++ that some small parts of the code have to be compiled only in debug mode ?

Comment: Are you using QMake or CMake with QtCreator?

Comment: QMake.. I have try #ifdef DEBUG, NDEBUG and _DEBUG but neither worked.. I guess I have to put them somewhere in the qmake project file ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to depend on the macro `NDEBUG`, which is used by the macro `assert()` defined in `<cassert>`:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
  // release mode code
#else
  // debug mode code
#endif
```

The opposite of `#ifdef` is `#ifndef`, and of course `#else` branches are optional.

If this macro doesn't work (for whatever reason), you

1. can try the macro `QT_NO_DEBUG`, which Qt uses for a similar purpose with `Q_ASSERT()`; and
2. should fix it so that `NDEBUG` is (un)defined correctly; it's required for `<cassert>` to work properly, and code you use may depend on it.

Comment: Thank you, using QT_NO_DEBUG or QT_DEBUG works the expected way.