# How to compile a piece of source code only in debug mode?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I would make sure that a piece of source code is compiled only when Qt Creator is set up to compile the current project in debug mode. Otherwise, if Qt Creator is set up to compile the source code of a project in release mode, this piece of source code should not be compiled.

Comment: Have you heard of `#ifdef`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain debug/release conditional compiling in C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537251/how-to-obtain-debug-release-conditional-compiling-in-c-program)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
  // do something (debug mode)
#endif
```

Should work